# Sum of two convex sets in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: terminology, convex-analysis

A friend of mine recently got an assignment, which asked for the sum of two convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is this sum referring to Minkowski addition or is there another meaning to it? (such as the union of the sets?)

[Click here to see what Minkowski addition is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition)

Comment: That's what I would guess, but the context of the assignment (and the instructor's statements) would be determinative.

Comment: Sum of $A$ and $B$ in a vector space is defined as $\{x\mid x=y+z, y \in A, z\in B\}$.

Comment: I would presume it is just the usual set sum as @njguliyev has written.

Comment: I turns out that we are talking about the same thing. I never heard the name "Minkowski sum".

Comment: @njguliyev Perhaps you want to promote your comments to an answer? That way, this question can be removed from the Unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just answer to take this out of the unanswered queue.

Yes, the sum of sets refers to Minkowski addition. As, njguliyev has said, the sum of $A$ and $B$ in a vector space can be defined as $\{x\mid x=y+z, y \in A, z\in B\}.$